# Electric potential for a continuous charge distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

First consider a small element on a planar object with charge $dq$. Taking $V=0$ at $r=\infty$, the potential $dV$ due to $dq$ at a point $P$ outside of the object is:

$$dV = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{dq}{r}$$
where $r$ is the distance between $P$ and $dq$.

To find the total potential $V$ due to all the charges in the object at $r$, we simply integrate:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V &= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \frac{dq}{r} \\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{r} 
\end{aligned}
$$

However, the distance $r$ to $P$ varies for each element $dq$. So is the equation saying that we can take the total charge Q of the object to be at a point? If so, where would the point be?

Answer (score 1):

You did not evaluate the integral over all $dq$ for your total potential correctly. r is different for each  $dq$ element of the planar object. So you have to consider a volume integral over the object with $dq=\rho dxdydz$ in the numerator and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ in the denominator, $\rho$ is the charge density. If the object has only surface charge you can use a surface integral with the surface charge density. r is the distance between the point in space where you are determining the potential and the location of the infinitesimal charge element.

Comment: So in polar coordinates, would $dV = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \rho dr d\theta$?

Comment: I'm only considering the distribution on a plane.

Comment: If you use polar coordinates to describe your planar charge distribution, you  have $dV = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R} \rho r dr d\theta$ where r is the distance of the charge element from the origin of the polar coordinate system and $R$ is the distance between the charge element and the point in space where you want to calculate the potential, and $\rho$ is now the areal density of charge. This $R$ is what you called before $r$ and it has to be expressed as a function of the polar coordinate $r$ in order to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Ah yes sorry. I forgot to mention that I was taking the test charge to be at the origin. Would there be any loss of generality?

Comment: If you want to calculate the potential everywhere in space around your charged object, you cannot calculate $V$  only at the origin.

Comment: sorry for the late comment, but would this mean that the $r$ in your answer should equal $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}$ instead? $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ are the coordinates of some arbitrary point where you measure the potential.

Comment: Yes, the  $x, y,z$ would then be the coordinates of the charge elements over which you have integrate.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last equality should be interpreted more as an aproximation than as an equality if you're dealing with a macroscopic object but its quite accurate if the distance from the object where you're measuring the potential is very big in comparison with any dimension of your object.  As you get closer to the object you should also take into account higher multipolar contributions. But as I said, if you're far enough you can consider the distribution as a point charge.

For you're last question I think the coordinates of the point should be calculated as a weighted average. If I'm not mistaken it would be the analogous as the center of mass of a "distribution of mass", so it would be the "center of charge" of the distribution of charge and you compute it in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the correct interpretation of this equation is the following:
$$ dV=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r}=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \rho(\vec{r}) \frac{d\Omega}{r}$$
where I have used $\vec{r}$ for the vector from the point where I will be integrating to point $P$, $\rho(\vec{r})$ for the charge density (as it has been already pointed, is analougous to the mass density: it is the charge per unit of volume at a given point in the space. I use $d\Omega$ for the element of volume since you have already used $dV$

The second expression you pointed is only valid for a point charge :) (You can extend it using Gauss theorem to other distributions with spherical symmetry). The charge density of a point charge is $Q$ where it is and 0 everywhere else (there is a mathematical object to describe this, known as  [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)).

As a counter example to your derivation when the charge is not point-like, I leave you the potential an infinite charged plane creates. The electric field can be obtained using Gauss law, yielding:
 $$ E=2\pi\sigma$$
where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density. As you may know, $E=-\frac{dV}{dx}$ with $x$ the direction normal to the plane. Then:
$$ V=-2\pi\sigma x$$
for every point P at a distance $x$ of the plane (if I have not made any mistake). This does nothing to do with what you obtained :).

Comment: I do not quite understand how you obtained the $dr$ in $\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \rho(\vec r) \frac{d\Omega}{dr}$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I am sorry, it is a mistake. I meant $d\Omega/r $. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec r_s=x_s\hat x+y_s\hat y$ be a point on your object, and $\vec r_P=x_P\hat x+y_P\hat y+z_P\hat z$ the location of your point $P$.  The small amount $dq_s$ of charge located at $\vec r_s$ will contribute
$$
dV=\frac{dq_s}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{\vert \vec r_p-\vec r_s\vert}=
\frac{dq_s}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_P-x_s)^2+(y_P-y_s)^2+z_P^2}}
$$
to the potential at $P$.  You then need to integrate over the location of the source charges, using $dq=\sigma_s(\vec r_s)dS$ where $\sigma_s(\vec r_s)$ is the surface charge density at $\vec r_s$ and $dS$ is the small area around $\vec r_s$ containing the charge $dq_s$.

In Cartesian coordinates you would thus get
$$
V=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\int 
\frac{dx_s\,dy_s \sigma_s(\vec r_s)}{\sqrt{(x_P-x_s)^2+(y_P-y_s)^2+z_P^2}}
$$
with the limits of integration determined by the boundary of your planar object.